# geo location is not working in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

Hi any one can you please help me what it does mean

```
 define("cordova/plugin/geolocation", function (require, exports, module) {

                        var argscheck = require('cordova/argscheck'),
                                utils = require('cordova/utils'),
                                exec = require('cordova/exec'),
                                PositionError = require('cordova/plugin/PositionError'),
                                Position = require('cordova/plugin/Position');
```

we need any extra flies required for working geo location in PhoneGap.

Can any one please help me..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change that code unless the geolocation plugin NOT installed and you are trying to install it manually.

I recommend the easy way: use the Cordova CLI interface.

Open a terminal/console, go to your project folder and run

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

This will install && add the geolocation plugin to your project.
Afterwards go to your .js file and add

```
function geolocationSuccess (position) {
    alert(position.coords.latitude); 
}
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess);
```

Comment: Hi @Ungureanu Liviu, it is saying "-bash: Cordova: command not found"